# How to build pop up of TableViewer in SWT?

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, jface, tableviewer

I am new in Java and in SWT.

I created `TableViewer` to show data of tables.

```
class myTable : TableViewer
```

I want when I press on button to open dialog of `myTable` ( like pop up ) and to choose any item from the `TableViewer`.

The dialog should have two buttons "OK" and cancel.

Do you know how to do it in java? I mean to open dialog with `TableViewer`

Does there is standard widget for this?

which component do I need to use?

Do you have any example?

Comment: If you want pure SWT you can only use `Table`. `TableViewer` is JFace. So are you building a SWT app or an Eclipse plug-in or RCP?

Comment: Eclipse rcp could be jface or swt

Comment: I am having TableViewer with JFace , I just want to open it as dailog or popup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest dialog would be one using `org.eclipse.jface.dialog.Dialog` - something like this:

```java
import org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.TableViewer;
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridData;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;

public class TestDialog extends Dialog
{
  public TestDialog(final Shell parentShell)
  {
    super(parentShell);
  }


  @Override
  protected Control createDialogArea(final Composite parent)
  {
    final Composite body = (Composite)super.createDialogArea(parent);

    final TableViewer viewer = new TableViewer(body, SWT.BORDER | SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.H_SCROLL);

    viewer.getTable().setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));

    // TODO: Set TableViewer content and label providers
    // TODO: Set TableViewer input

    return body;
  }
}
```

In your code you do:

```
TestDialog dialog = new TestDialog(shell);

dialog.open();   // Displays the dialog in a popup window
```

Comment: Does the dialog will open a new screen like popup ?

Comment: How do I add column and row to this table?

Comment: @Jeevan If you have a question then Ask a Question. Or read a tutorial such as [this one](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseJFaceTable/article.html)

Comment: Thank you for the link. @greg-449